# How to make a widget animate based on child's size?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, `AnimatedContainer`does not work when you want it to animate based on child's size, it works only on its predefined attributes (like color, decoration, width, height, etc...).

How to make a container animate its width/height when it's children get bigger or smaller, or receive more widgets inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AnimatedSize`. Every time its children gets bigger/smaller or receives more children inside it, it animates.

```
AnimatedSize(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[

      SizedBox(
        width:  _box1Width,
        height:  _box1Height,
      ),

      SizedBox(
        width:  _box2Width,
        height:  _box2Height,
      ),

      SizedBox(
        width:  _box3Width,
        height:  _box3Height,
      ),

    ],
  ),
```